# Custom grep file output

Tags: linux, printing, grep

I'm running the command below:

```
for line in $(cat file1.txt); do cat file2.txt | grep ${line}; done
```

and it´s works fine..but I'm looking a way to print the results in a file like this:

```
$(line) - grep result
```

Is there a way to customize my `grep` output?

Thanks

Comment: I question the claim that this "works fine".  By `$(line)`, did you mean `${line}`?

Comment: Are you iterating over the contents of `file.txt`, or are you intending to execute `file1.txt` and iterate over the output, each line of which is a command that you execute and search for the output of in `file2.txt`?

Comment: Hi, my typo during the question...the correct is ${line}

Comment: You should [edit] the question to correct that typo then.

Comment: It is unclear what you expect the output to be. `$(variable) runs `variable` as a command.  It is further unclear what you are looping over.

Answer (score 0):

```
file1="file1.txt";
file2="file2.txt";
for line in $file1; do 
    result=$(cat $file2 | grep $line | sed -e :a -e N -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g'));
    echo "$line-$result";
done
```

if the result of $(cat file2.txt | grep $line) are multi lines, you should implement to echo with for statement.

```
for line in $(file1.txt); do 
    result=$(cat file2.txt | grep $line);
    echo $line
    for _line in $result; do
        echo "  -$_line";
    done
done
```

Comment: Each instance of `$(line)` tries to run a command `line`, so I don't think this works.

Comment: `$(file1.txt)` tries to run `file1.txt` as a command. This still doesn't work.

Comment: Why save the result of `grep` in a variable anyway? Why looping over the files? Doesn't `grep -f` work?

Comment: Guys, using the @eric-lee 's solution, the shell is returning the grep results correctly, but not concatenated.

Comment: you should remove break line("\n") with sed or other command.